# старт стоп кнопки

Tags: css, веб-программирование

Надо сделать кнопки `старт` и `стоп` на css как на картинке

[image: https://scontent.fkbp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-9/42663235_1669094326534698_2220919269409947648_n.png?_nc_cat=100&oh=9c6370c9aae2c07a98f109b86a271bb5&oe=5C23726E]

но я не знаю как сделать круглую рамку

```css
#start {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  /*border-radius: 10px;*/
}

#stop {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-width: 30px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
  width: 10px;
  border-border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="start">
  </div>
  <div id="stop">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Картинку подкрепите (не  ссылку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подправил ваш код:

```css
.round{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius:100px;
  border:2px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#start {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  /*border-radius: 10px;*/
}

#stop {
  margin-left:20px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  border-width: 15px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent green;
  width: 10px;
  border-border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="round">
   <div id="start">

   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="round">
   <div id="stop">

   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно еще сделать фигуры через картинки background-image.

Comment: Спасибо, размер уже под себя переделаю.

Answer (score 0):

```css
#start,
#stop {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #007bff;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#start:before,
#stop:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

#start:before {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 6px 0 6px 10px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent darkgreen;
  margin-left: 1px;
}

#stop:before {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: darkred;
}
```

```html
<div id="start"></div>
<div id="stop"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, этот код поставлю если с тем не получится. К сожалению не могу 2 галочки поставить, но ценю Вашу помощь!